# Filtro Excel para ordenar columna, lo detecta como String y no Int

Tags: excel

tengo un problema, como podeis ver en la foto, tengo una columna que quiero que el orden que siga al aplicarle algún filtro, sea :
1.1,
1.2,
1.3,
1.4,
1.5,
1.6,
1.7,
1.8,
1.9,
1.10,
1.11,
1.12..
..
2.1.1,
2.1.2,
2.1.3..
..
2.1.10,
2.1.11..
..
3.1,
3.2,
3.3..

Pero claro lo que obtengo, es que la columna me la detecta como texto, y me deja ordenarlo como tal de la A-Z, y lo que quiero es aplicarle un filtro personalizado que me saque el orden que he puesto arriba.

[image: Como me los ordena]

[image: La opción de filtro que me da]

Comment: La única solución que se me ocurre es utilizar otra columna tipo "Jerarquía" o índice o algo así en la que hagas el equivalente numérico calculando, por ejemplo, lo que hay antes del `.` multiplicando por 1000 y sumando lo que hay después, porque ese sería el equivalente numérico de esa columna

Comment: @VFG muchísimas gracias!! lo he solucionado tal cual me has dicho, me ha costado sacar lo que hay antes del punto del numero de la celda, y lo que hay después pero he dado con la tecla.

Answer (score 0):

Pimero he tenido que cambiar en opciones-> avanzadas-> opciones de edición-> y he desmarcado separadores del sistema, y he puesto tanto el separador decimal como el de miles que sea  el '.', gracias a esto la columna ya la ha interpretado excel como valores númericos y no cadena de carácteres.

He creado dos columnas: Parte Entera (los dígitos hasta el primer punto) y Parte Decimal (todo lo restante del primer punto hacia delante), esto lo he hecho aplicando las siguientes fórmulas:

Parte Entera: =EXTRAE(B2;1;ENCONTRAR(".";B2;1)-1)
Parte Decimal: =EXTRAE(B2;ENCONTRAR(".";B2)+1;LARGO(B2)-ENCONTRAR(".";B2))

Ahora ya para que se aplique bien la ordenacion basta con dar en el filtro de la columna Jerarquía y poner de menor a mayor, y ya nos saldra nuestra columna "Nº" con el orden que se quería.

[image]

Comment: Exacto. Bien hecho. Y las columnas de parte entera y/o parte decimal incluso podrías ocultarlas. Otro comentario... en tu pregunta inical sólo se veían dos niveles de jerarquía. Si tienes 3 como se ve en esta respuesta... habría que hacer más cálculos (Por ejemplo, por 1.000 y por 1.000.000. Porque si no, te puede pasar lo mismo con 2.1.31 y con 2.1.3